# C# - Extending existing framework sealed class

Tags: c#, class, frameworks, extension-methods, sealed

Consider the sealed framework class "WorkItem" ([MSDN-description)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem(v=vs.120).aspx)

I would like to extend this sealed class so I can write extension methods of the class e.g. I could write:

```
workitem.ReadWrite();
```

Is this possible to implement, if so how could it be done?

Comment: A sealed class only means you can't inherit it, it doesn't mean you can't write extension methods for it.

Comment: Extension methods are not members of the "this" type. They only enable the invocation syntax as if they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much possible to add extension methods to `sealed` classes. You can simply create an extension method for a `sealed` class like a `concrete` class.

You can write like this for your class, Also you need to include the `assembly` and use the `namespace` of the Extensions class where you will be using the method.

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static void ReadWrite(this WorkItem item)
    {
        // Do your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example of Extension Method:

```
public static class WorkItemExtensions
    {
        public static void ReadWrite(this WorkItem objRef)
        {
            // Do things you need here
        }
    }
```